# HTML5 .mov video not working on *some* Safari + Mac

Tags: macos, safari, html5-video

I have embedded HTML5 video(s) in a site - http://dev.thejoint.com - where they work in Firefox, Chrome, IE9 (ahem, ahem) and Opera but not in Safari on *some* Macs. They even work in iPhone and Android.

On my iMac, it works fine. The .mov file even works on Windows + Safari combination, since we know we have to install Quicktime for that.

Worst part is, the video works in Safari browser directly - http://dev.thejoint.com/media1/jointsequence.mov - but not on the page where it has been embedded.

I have tried every possible thing with web.config and IIS to add the MIME types as well.

Hope someone has some insight, because this is the only things remaining in completing off the project.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, <video> only works in Safari if QuickTime is installed.  I don't know if this affects Macs also, but it could be the cause.

Comment: I don't think the issue was QuickTime. The issue was never resolved.